# Don't include android.R here; use a fully qualified name for each usage instead

Tags: java, android

When I import `android.R` I get Error_1 and the Error_2 is solved. So, how do I solve Error_1. I've tried changing `import android.R` --> `import com.example.testing.R`. However it is still not working.

Even my login.xml seems to be find. No error. I've also tried cleaning the project. Still nothing happens.

**LoginActivity.java**

```
package com.example.testing;

import android.R;  //Error_1 : Don't include android.R here; use a fully qualified name for each usage instead
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity 
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setting default screen to login.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.login); //Error_2 : login cannot be resolved or is not a field
        TextView registerScreen = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.link_to_register);

        //Listening to register new account link
        registerScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //Switching to Register Screen
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class); 
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my login.xml

**login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="#ffffff">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@layout/header_gradient" 
    android:paddingTop="5dip"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip"> 
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Footer -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:contentDescription="@string/description"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="90dip"
    android:background="@layout/footer_repeat"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:padding="10dip" 
    android:layout_below="@id/header">

 <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textColor="#372c24"
     android:text="@string/name" />

 <EditText android:id="@+id/editText1"
     android:hint="@string/edit_message"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
     android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
     android:singleLine="true"/>

      <!--  Password Label -->
      <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#372c24"
            android:text="@string/password"/>

      <EditText android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:hint="@string/edit_message1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>

      <Button android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:text="@string/login"/>

      <TextView android:id="@+id/link_to_register"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dip"
            android:text="@string/loginDesc"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#0b84aa"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Login Form Ends -->
 </RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: It should be `import com.example.testing.R`? Do you have `link_to_register` defined as id in your xml? Can you post the relevant part?

Comment: Are there any errors in your res folder ?

Comment: please post your xml part as the problem is with your xml actually

Comment: if you have any errors in your res folder it won't generate R file for your project..

Comment: remove `import android.R;` and restart eclipse.

Comment: @Szymon yes I've defined link_to_register as id. I've posted it already

Comment: @Prince nope there's no error

Answer (score 2):

1. make sure there are no errors in your XML
2. if any correct those and Project->Build All
3. if everything went good, there wont be a red cross near your XML [well im referring to eclipse IDE]
4. you dont have to import android.R it's visible and accessible in every source file unless you have altered properties

NOTE: you might have an issue of having a .out file in your res folder, this is a bug of eclipse that occurs when you try to compile the project while a XML fiole is open. If so delete it and try

Answer (score 1):

you should import com.example.testing.R remove  import android.R and check login.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly remove import android.R and then

1. Try cleaning the Projects from Project Tab.
2. Close eclipse and start again.

Step 1. worked for me.

Comment: The question does say "*I've also tried cleaning the project.*", which presumably is followed by trying to build again. Likewise, [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872651/dont-include-android-r-here-use-a-fully-qualified-name-for-each-usage-instead/34726671#comment29560718_19872651) tells the user to "*restart eclipse*" which presumably didn't work.

Comment: Worked for me too, but in Android Studio.